# Why does my Array always have 0s in it when it should have nothing in it - C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm working on something for school, just a basic score calculator. I know it's not the prettiest code, but it works and that's more what the class is focused on here at the beginning.

The only issue that I have is that whenever I click "Display" it prints out 20 0s. 20 is the length of the array. Everything else is working. It adds the number I input into the array and replaces the 0s. But I don't want it to have 0s at all unless I specifically type them in.

Any help is appreciated.

Full code:

```
// Creates the list that displays the score
List<string> scoreList = new List<string>();

// Array to store up to 20 scores
int[] scoreArray = new int[20];

// class level variable to store current open slot in the array
int openSlot = 0;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
// Initializes variables that hold our math total and count of numbers entered
int total = 0;
int count = 0;

private void btnExit_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}

private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (openSlot <= scoreArray.GetUpperBound(0))
    {
        try
        {
            // Basic math for conversion of entered number and calculating total numbers entered
            // and the averages of those numbers
            int score = Convert.ToInt32(txtScore.Text);
            total += score;
            count += 1;
            int average = total / count;
            txtScoreTotal.Text = total.ToString();
            txtScoreCount.Text = count.ToString();
            txtAverage.Text = average.ToString();
            txtScore.Focus();
        }
        catch(System.FormatException) // Makes sure that the user enters valid character into box
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter valid number into box");
            return;
        }

        // Adds the most recent entered number to the Score List
            scoreList.Add(txtScore.Text);
        }

        // if statement to make sure that there is still room in the array to store the
        // new entry
        if (openSlot > scoreArray.GetUpperBound(0)) // GetUpperBound(0) returns the index of the last element in the first dimension
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The array is full! The most recent number was not added.");
            txtScore.SelectAll();
            txtScore.Focus();
            return;
        }
        // Assigns a variable as an integer from the score text box
        // to allow us to numerically sort the numbers in the scoreArray
        int scoreParse = Int32.Parse(txtScore.Text);

        // move the most recent number to the current open slot in the score array
        scoreArray[openSlot] = scoreParse;

        // add 1 to openSlot
        openSlot += 1;
    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clears all input fields and resets variables to 0
        openSlot = 0;
        total = 0;
        count = 0;
        txtScore.Text = "";
        txtScoreTotal.Text = "";
        txtScoreCount.Text = "";
        txtAverage.Text = "";
        txtScore.Focus();

        // Clears the array and list
        int[] clearScoreArray = new int[20];
        scoreArray = clearScoreArray;
        List<string> clearScoreList = new List<string>();
        scoreList = clearScoreList;
    }

    private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // If array has no stored values, display a MessageBox that informs user
        if (scoreArray == null || scoreArray.Length == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There are no numbers to display");
            return;
        }

        //move focus to the code textbox
        txtScore.Focus();

        // Creates a blank string variable named scr to input the scores into
        // for the MessageBox
        string scr = "";
        foreach (var scoreAdded in scoreArray)
        {
            // Adds variable scr as the string to display 
            scr += scoreAdded + "\n";
        }
        // Sorts the array from lowest to highest number
        Array.Sort(scoreArray);

        // Displays a message box with the scores that were added
        MessageBox.Show(scr);
    }
}
```

Comment: `0` is the default value for `int`, not 'nothing'.

Comment: The default values of numeric array elements are set to zero, and reference elements are set to null.

Comment: `int` has a default value of 0, you can use `int?` (nullable type) and check if the value is null before adding it to the output string.

Comment: Use `List<int>` then, but not `int[]`.

Comment: The issue with using int? is that the MessageBox still has the same height as having the 20 0s displaying, and the if statement to search for Null value when displaying doesn't work. It still just displays the MessageBox with no values.

Comment: So instead of a `foreach` loop, use a `for` loop and only loop up to your `count` variable. Then you won't get the empty values. That would work for either `int` or `int?` (using `int` is better in my opinion as there's no need to check for `null`) though I agree the easiest is just to use a `List<int>`. Also you have an **error in your average calculation**. You need to *cast* at least one of the values to, and store the result as `double` otherwise you end up with integer division where, for example, `10/4==2` and *not* `2.5`

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

When an object is initially declared there is a default initialization value. In this case, `0` is the default value for an `int` in C#. The default value can often be changed at the initialization of the object if there's a supporting constructor.

When the `int[] scoreArray = new int[20];` is declared, all 20 variables are assigned the value of 0. This is because C# does not allow uninitialized variables.

This link shows all default initialization values for `C#`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/default-values-table

Comment: Right, but why are all 20 slots in the array always filled with 0 until replaced?

Comment: @KeithTerry Think of the array as a place holder for 20 linked integers. Each integer in the array behaves as a normal integer. When an integer is created, it must be assigned to a value at the creation of the variable. In this case, all 20 are assigned the value of 0.

Comment: @KeithTerry *The initial value of each of the elements of an array is the default value of the type of the array elements.* [Specification](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/variables.md#array-elements)

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a set amount of arrays (In your place it's 20), they get some sort of value, normally it's 0. Keep this is mind when you are using myArrayHere.length, cause it will check how many arrays have been declared (int[] array) and initialized (... = new array[]), not how many have been modified (given a value).

Best solution, IMO is creating a function, that would know how many elements in an array you will need or how many of them you are using (just have a function, that returns the amount of used variables, by checking it with a loop, and then modifying it later on... but that is one way to fix this issue, and there are better fixes than these I pointed out, but as I see you are newer to C# (prob.) fixing your issues with ok'ish code is good, as your first project should be meant for learning, later on, you can improve it and heck, if you are looking to become a pro, take some Programming courses on how to improve your code in general).

Good luck!
-Normantas

Answer (score 0):

You can use nullable if you dont want zero as default value.

int? [] array = new int?[20] ;